# How do I handle Multiple Routes In App.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm new to react and now learning react-router.

I am trying to have multiple routes within the BrowserRouter and I am not sure why it isn't working.

My code is this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {database} from '../firebase';
import _ from 'lodash';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import List from './List';
import NewPost from './NewPost';

class App extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App container">
      <header className="App-header">

          <h1 className="App-title">Here We Go Again</h1>
        </header>
        <hr/>
       <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' component={List}/>
          <Route path='/new' component={NewPost}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter> 
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Regardless of the path I go to, it only shows the first one in the list. I have tried moving them around so I know that for sure. And the functionality of them all still work. It's just a matter of rendering them one at a time.

```
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' component={List}/>
          <Route path='/new' component={NewPost}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

As you can see I tried some other possible solutions on stack overflow liek adding Switch but it still didn't work.

Any idea how to fix it or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the word `exact` to the first route. It is currently matching anything with a `/`.

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/' exact component={List}/>
      <Route path='/new' component={NewPost}/>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I'm new, can you explain what you mean and how to add it?  And does that mean that other than adding exact, everything else is ok? Just to be sure

Comment: More information in the docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: @Al-m Yep! I just added an example!

Comment: @LukeSchlangen It works perfectly thank you!! I assume this would work with no matter how many routes I add yeah?

Comment: That's right! It means that specific route will only match the `/` route exactly regardless of how many you have, and the `Switch` means it will only match one of the `Route`s.